# Need code of Half and Full adder using Visual Prolog using basis 2-AND-NOT

Tags: prolog

I`m writing code on visual prolog 8,
I have to write Adder and half adder, using the table of truth and use a basis 2-AND-NOT
Schemes I made:
half adder

[image: half adder]

and a full adder

[image: full adder]

Have you got any ideas, how to make this work?

Comment: Like with any programming problem you first have to define some general things. What kind of query/call do you want to make at the top level? What are the inputs and outputs? How can you represent your given information? Your drawing is very cryptic. I assume it's a circuit with flip-flops and and/or gates but they aren't properly marked. You can represent these with Prolog facts. Have you written much Prolog yet? If not, then you need to do more reading. You can also get some ideas googling "Prolog electronic circuit" or similar terms.

Comment: 1st picture is a half-adder - it has 2 inputs and 2 outputs - answer and overflow. And, no, I haven`t got an experience with Prolog yet.
2nd picture is a full-adder. It has 2 inputs+1 input (P) is overflow from a half-adder. And it has (Full Adder) 2 outputs - answer and overflow.

Such code makes simple AND-NOT functionality and I get simple truth table:

Comment: https://image.ibb.co/dHFEFG/123.jpg

Comment: Your full adder doesn't show a carry out, which is also an output of the full adder. I would assume you'd have two predicates. Something like `half_adder(A, B, S, C)` where `A` and `B` are the input bits, and `S` and `C` are the sum and carry, respectively. For full adder, you'd have `full_adder(A, B, Cin, S, Cout)` with similar meaning, except here you'd have a carry input (`Cin`) and a carry output `Cout`.

Comment: The rest is just following the logic. If you want `X and not (Y and Z)` in Prolog using the basic `and/2` and `not/1` facts, you'd write it something like, `and(Y, Z, AYZ), not(AYZ, NAYZ), and(X, NAYZ, R).` where `R` is the result. That should be enough to get you o the right path I think. I don't know if that image you posted is your own code or what. If you want help with specific problems in code you wrote, you need to copy the code to your question and ask it. Don't just put a link in the comments to an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ISO Prolog, you could do the following:

```
halfadd(X, Y, Z, C) :-
   Z is X xor Y,
   C is X /\ Y.

fulladd(X, Y, C, Z, D) :-
   halfadd(X, Y, H, J),
   halfadd(H, C, Z, K),
   D is J \/ K.
```

Looks right to me:

```
X Y C|Z D
-----+---
0 0 0|0 0
0 0 1|1 0
0 1 0|1 0
0 1 1|0 1
1 0 0|1 0
1 0 1|0 1
1 1 0|0 1
1 1 1|1 1
```